# Merging point features into one feature and create ID table containing name of each point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, attribute-table, merge

I have 510 point features in separate shapefiles each representing bus stops and I want to merge them into one feature shp containing an ID column for the bus line number each bus stop belongs to.

How would I do so?

Comment: I would use Append but you will need the bus line in that ID field for each point in each input shapefile first.

Answer (score 1):

To work with all of the bus stops in one layer while preserving their individual attributes, I would try a multipart to singlepart conversion.

First, select all the bus stops either by attribute, location, or manually. Then, save this selection as its own layer. Next, use the geoprocessing tool multipart to singlepart with this new layer as your input, and create a new layer for it to be saved as.

This should store all your bus stops as one feature, while preserving each stop's attributes.